# Materials and infrared images

Tags: infrared-radiation

I don't know much about infrared waves so I was hoping someone could point me to the right direction..

I'm currently playing around with a Microsoft Kinect v2 sensor which can take depth and infrared images.(the depth image is calculated from the infrared)

I was wondering whether the infrared images can be used to infer information other than the depth.. I know that some materials block out IR and stuff but is it possible to somehow get the probability of the existence of a certain material given an IR image? ( Sorry if I worded it weirdly but I hope you get the drift..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The near-infrared range isn't really that much different to ordinary red light.  It's just such a deep red that our eyes can barely see it.

So some things will be dark, and others light, according to what colour they are.  That doesn't tell you much about what they are made of.